# Import all .TXT files in mulitple subsubfolder into sepreate workbooks

Tags: vba, loops, excel, import

I'm quite a novice when it comes to VBA so any help is greatly appreciated,  I've got a macro that lists all subfolders and subsubfolders in specified root directory `C:Users\Abubakar Adan\JSIM\Ic=340uA\` these subsubfodlers contain 101 .txt files. numbered 1-101 The issue I have now is that I now need to import the content of the subsubfolders i.e. the .TXT files into a single workbook in a true chronological order i.e. after running the code each subsubfolder that contains .TXT files would now have a new workbook which in itself would contain the imported .TXT data in a true chronological order

Any help with either modifying my macro or suggestions of a new macro are welcome. honestly any help is truly appreciated, and thank you in advance for taking the time to read this, again any help is truly appreciated. here is a link to the demo file created [Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s0uc6fvzjsb84ih/Demo.txt)

```
     Option Explicit

' * These routines use File System Object.  For the easiest use of File System
'   Objects, it is necessary to create a reference to the Microsoft Scripting
'   Runtime as follows:
'     1) Open the Visual Basic Editor.
'     2) Select Tools, from the tool bar, then References.
'     3) You will get a long list of available references of which a few will be
'        ticked.
'     4) The list is in alphabetic sequence.  Scroll down the list looking for
'        "Microsoft Scripting Runtime".  Tick the box against it and then click OK.
'     5) Select Tools, from the tool bar, then References again.  Check that
'        "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" is one of the ticked references at the top.
'        If it is not, you did not perform step 4 correctly.

Sub CtrlSearch()

  Dim FlSys As FileSystemObject
  Dim FlTextOut As TextStream
  Dim PathCrnt As String
  Dim PathSearchRoot As String

  PathCrnt = ActiveWorkbook.Path

  Set FlSys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set FlTextOut = FlSys.CreateTextFile(PathCrnt & "\Demo.txt")

  PathSearchRoot = "C:\Users\Abubakar Adan\JSIM\Ic=340uA"

  ' ### Replace "C:\DataArea\Play" with the full name of the folder to search.

  Call SearchSingleFolder(PathSearchRoot, 0, FlTextOut)

  FlTextOut.Close

End Sub
Sub SearchSingleFolder(ByVal PathSearch As String, ByVal Lvl As Long, _
                       ByRef FlTextOut As TextStream)

  ' PathSearch  A path to be searched.
  ' Lvl         The level of this call.  Used to control indenting
  ' FlTextOut   The file object for the text file to which paths and
  '             files are to be output

  ' * When this routine is called by CtrlSearch, PathSearch will be the root of
  '   the folders to be searched and Lvl will be 0.
  ' * When this routine is called by itself, PathSearch will be a sub-folder
  '   or a sub-sub-folder of the root folders to be searched and Lvl will be 1 for
  '   a sub-folder, 2 for a sub-sub-folder and so on.
  ' * This routine outputs PathSearch to the output file following by the names of
  '   the files within it.
  ' * The routine then calls itself for each sub-folder of PathSearch.

  Dim Fldr As Folder
  Dim FldrSubCrnt As Folder
  Dim FlCrnt As File
  Dim FlSys As FileSystemObject
  Dim ws As Worksheet

  Set FlSys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

  FlTextOut.WriteLine (Space(Lvl * 2) & PathSearch)

  ' ### This routine is called for the root folder and every folder within
  ' ### the root folder.  If any folder level processing is required, it must
  ' ### be added here.  PathSearch is the current folder name.

  Set Fldr = FlSys.GetFolder(PathSearch)

  For Each FlCrnt In Fldr.Files
    FlTextOut.WriteLine (Space(Lvl * 2 + 4) & FlCrnt.Name)

      ' ### This loop will process every file within the root folder and every
      ' ### folder within the root folder.  The full name of the file is:
      ' ###    PathSearch & "\" & FlCrnt.Name
      ' ### If the folders may contain files that are not to be processed, code
      ' ### must be included to exclude such files.  For example, if you only want
      ' ### to process text files you need something like:
If LCase(Right(FlCrnt.Name, 4)) = ".TXT" Then
Set ws = Sheets.Add
With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;" & "PathSearch, & FlCrnt.Name", Destination:=Range("$A$2")) 'The import code does nothing, I was hoping to import every subsubflder to its own workbook
        .Name = FlCrnt.Name
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 1251
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = True
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
 End If

  Next

  For Each FldrSubCrnt In Fldr.SubFolders
    Call SearchSingleFolder(PathSearch & "\" & FldrSubCrnt.Name, Lvl + 1, FlTextOut)
  Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry there was a mistake in the first version of this comment which I have deleted.  I have no suitable text files so I cannot test your code. However I can see errors that would prevent the code working. If it is possible that FlCrnt is not a file you wish to import, you must check the name. For example, check the extension is "TXT" or "txt". Consider: `With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= "TEXT;" & "PathSearchRoot, & *.TXT", ...` You must replace `PathSearchRoot` by `PathSearch`. You must replace `*.TXT` with `FlCrnt.Name`.

Comment: Thank you again for your help and your patients with me, after studying your code properly and doing some further reading I've updated my question to better represent what it is I'm looking for, The first half of the macro works perfectly but the import code doesn't work and I'm not sure why nothing is happening when I click F5 except the creation of the demo.txt file

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** The macro I provide writes folder and file names to a text file.  This demonstrates that the macro is searching all the folders under a root folder and can access all files within those folders.  In the original draft, I did not make clear where the OP should add his code.  I have added comments to the macro, identifying where code should be added.

I do not fully understand your question.  However, I believe I understand the major problem.

Folder `C:Users\Abubakar Adan\JSIM\` contains many sub-folders and perhaps sub-sub-folders.  Each of those sub-folders and sub-sub-folders contain text files which you wish to convert to workbooks.  You do not know how to access all those files within their sub-folders and sub-sub-folders.

The macros below demonstrate how to access sub-folders and sub-sub-folders and sub-sub-sub-folders to any depth.

This answer is more advanced that I would wish.  However, I cannot think of a simpler way of giving you the flexibility I believe you need.  The macros are not long so you can work through them statement by statement and study what they are doing.

I am using "System File Objects" which give you full access to the Windows file system.  The internet has some good tutorials on "System File Objects" which I suggest you study if my code is unclear.

I create a text file, "Demo.txt", within the folder containing the workbook containing the macros.  To this text file, I write the name of every sub-folder and every file within a sub-folder.  I do not know how many files you have within `C:Users\Abubakar Adan\JSIM\`.  You could try the macros on `C:Users\Abubakar Adan\` to give you a better feel for what they do.

I use recursion.  Nowadays this is considered an advanced technique although I was taught it on my first programming course.  You will perhaps know that subroutine ABC can call subroutine DEF can call subroutine GHI to any depth (subject to memory).  You may not know that subroutine ABC can call itself.  This is recursion.

Recursion is very helpful when you are working down a hierarchy.  The code to handle the root folder, `C:Users\Abubakar Adan\JSIM\`, is exactly the same as the code to handle sub-folders and sub-sub-folders.  In every case, the code lists the folder name and the names of any files within it.  It then calls itself for every sub-folder.

Try the macros.  I believe they give you the skeleton of what you seek.  Where I output the name of a file to "Demo.txt", you will check that the extension is "TXT" and, if it is, use your existing code to convert it to a workbook.

I hope all this is clear.  Come back with questions as necessary.

```
Option Explicit

' * These routines use File System Object.  For the easiest use of File System
'   Objects, it is necessary to create a reference to the Microsoft Scripting
'   Runtime as follows:
'     1) Open the Visual Basic Editor.
'     2) Select Tools, from the tool bar, then References.
'     3) You will get a long list of available references of which a few will be
'        ticked.
'     4) The list is in alphabetic sequence.  Scroll down the list looking for
'        "Microsoft Scripting Runtime".  Tick the box against it and then click OK.
'     5) Select Tools, from the tool bar, then References again.  Check that
'        "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" is one of the ticked references at the top.
'        If it is not, you did not perform step 4 correctly.

Sub CtrlSearch()

  Dim FlSys As FileSystemObject
  Dim FlTextOut As TextStream
  Dim PathCrnt As String
  Dim PathSearchRoot As String

  PathCrnt = ActiveWorkbook.Path

  Set FlSys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set FlTextOut = FlSys.CreateTextFile(PathCrnt & "\Demo.txt")

  PathSearchRoot = "C:\DataArea\Play"

  ' ### Replace "C:\DataArea\Play" with the full name of the folder to search.

  Call SearchSingleFolder(PathSearchRoot, 0, FlTextOut)

  FlTextOut.Close

End Sub
Sub SearchSingleFolder(ByVal PathSearch As String, ByVal Lvl As Long, _
                       ByRef FlTextOut As TextStream)

  ' PathSearch  A path to be searched.
  ' Lvl         The level of this call.  Used to control indenting
  ' FlTextOut   The file object for the text file to which paths and
  '             files are to be output

  ' * When this routine is called by CtrlSearch, PathSearch will be the root of
  '   the folders to be searched and Lvl will be 0.
  ' * When this routine is called by itself, PathSearch will be a sub-folder
  '   or a sub-sub-folder of the root folders to be searched and Lvl will be 1 for
  '   a sub-folder, 2 for a sub-sub-folder and so on.
  ' * This routine outputs PathSearch to the output file following by the names of
  '   the files within it.
  ' * The routine then calls itself for each sub-folder of PathSearch.

  Dim Fldr As Folder
  Dim FldrSubCrnt As Folder
  Dim FlCrnt As File
  Dim FlSys As FileSystemObject

  Set FlSys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

  FlTextOut.WriteLine (Space(Lvl * 2) & PathSearch)

  ' ### This routine is called for the root folder and every folder within
  ' ### the root folder.  If any folder level processing is required, it must
  ' ### be added here.  PathSearch is the current folder name.

  Set Fldr = FlSys.GetFolder(PathSearch)

  For Each FlCrnt In Fldr.Files
    FlTextOut.WriteLine (Space(Lvl * 2 + 4) & FlCrnt.Name)

      ' ### This loop will process every file within the root folder and every
      ' ### folder within the root folder.  The full name of the file is:
      ' ###    PathSearch & "\" & FlCrnt.Name
      ' ### If the folders may contain files that are not to be processed, code
      ' ### must be included to exclude such files.  For example, if you only want
      ' ### to process text files you need something like:
      ' ###    If LCase(Right(FlCrnt.Name,4)) = ".txt" Then
      ' ###      ' Code to process file here
      ' ###    End If

  Next

  For Each FldrSubCrnt In Fldr.SubFolders
    Call SearchSingleFolder(PathSearch & "\" & FldrSubCrnt.Name, Lvl + 1, FlTextOut)
  Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey thank you for the reply just got a question. From what I understand the first macro seems to search through the directory specified so for your example in your example that would be C:\DataArea\Play and for my code it I would Change it to C:\Users\Abubakar Adan\JSIM\Ic=340uA, and If I've understood the materical about recusion that I've found online, I  would try and place the import macro after the `Set FlSys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")` line but I get the error Next i invalid command I've updated my code so that I only need change one folder in the folder path

Comment: I do not understand what you have added to be told `Next i` is an invalid command.  `FlTextOut.WriteLine (Space(Lvl * 2 + 4) & FlCrnt.Name)` displays every filename in the hierarchy.  That is where you add the code to open the file and process it.  You do not need to add a loop because I have already provided one.

Comment: hey sorry for not making myself clear, basically I copied and pasted my previous import macro in to your recursion procedure and was hoping that it would just work which was silly of myself. I have now read some material on recursion and on your suggestion I've reworked my macro and have changed the my original post to the one im using now but I'm not sure how to set it so that it only import the text files into multiple worksheets save the workbook and move to the next sub folder and repeat the procedure. I hope this makes sense and I really do you taking the time to help thank you

Comment: I have just seen your message.  I will try your new code in the next few hours and respond when I have something to say.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to version 2 question**

*Mistakes in existing code*

```
If LCase(Right(FlCrnt.Name, 4)) = ".TXT" Then
```

On the left you use `LCase` to ensure the extension is lower case but on the right you have upper case ".TXT".  Change `LCase` to `UCase` or ".TXT" to ".txt".

```
"TEXT;" & "PathSearch, & FlCrnt.Name"
```

You have the path and files names in quotes so they are literals rather than variables.  You have omitted the "\"; see seven lines up.  Replace by:

```
"TEXT;" & PathSearch & "\" & FlCrnt.Name
```

*Missing code*

You say you want to create a new workbook per folder that contains text files of interest.  There is no code to add a new workbook to the workbooks collection at the start of a folder nor code to save the updated workbook at the end of the folder.

You would only want to create a workbook if the folder contains text files of interest.  From the file you provide, I deduce the names of the text files of interest are of the format:

```
nnn_OUT_Ix_mmm.TXT
```

where:

- nnn rises from 1 to 101 in steps of 1.
- mmm falls from 500 to 0 then rises back to 500 in steps of 10.
- Neither nnn nor mmm have leading zeros.

I believe the easiest approach would be to generate these file names.  If file "1_OUT_Ix_500.TXT" exists within a folder then assume all the other files exist.

It is unclear if you want each text file in its own worksheet or if you want them added one after the other to the same worksheet.  If the first, your existing code will need little amendment although you may wish to change the worksheet names.  If the second, you will need to calculate the destination cell for each file and not change the worksheet name for each file.

Comment: The .TXT files are of the form nnn_OUT_Ix_mmm.TXT where nnn rises from 1 to 101 in steps of 1 but mmm falls from 500 to -500 in steps of 10 so in the folder there are 101 files 1_OUT_Ix_500.TXT to 101_OUT_Ix_-500.TXT, I'm hoping that each nnn_OUT_Ix_mmm.TXT will occupy its own worksheet and change the worksheet name to correspond to the imported file. the way the files are generated means I cannot have zero padding at nnn in your opinion what can I do to ensure that the files are imported in chronological order,

Comment: I had not noticed the difference between "underline hyphen" and "underline".  That makes the generation much easier.  I would open "1_OUT_lx_500.txt" then "2_OUT_lx_490.txt" then "3_OUT_lx_480.txt" and so on.  With atext file per worksheet your existing import code will need little change.

Comment: that is exactly what I'm looking for I have tried declaring `For i = 1 To 101` and changing  `PathSearch & "\" & FlCrnt.Name` to `PathSearch & "\ & i & "& FlCrnt.Name` and place `next i` under `End if` but when I compile the macro I receive the error **End if without block if** any idea as to why this would be the case

Comment: Why is the `Next i` under the `End If`?  `If` to `End If` and `For` to `Next` MUST be properly nested.

Comment: Im really sorry  for my ignorance and again really appreciate your patient. I've corrected the nesting issue. the final issue that I have is when i run the corrected macro I get run-time error 1004 Excel cannot find the text fileto refresh this external data range and `.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=True`is hilighted I think my error stems from the import code with 'PathSearch & "\" & "& i &" & FlCrnt.Name' where I have tired to include i into the import procedure but I literally have no idea how to correct this

Comment: Why the `& i` in the middle of the path/file name?

Comment: from what I read and littl vba experiance I have it seemed that after I declare `For i = 1 To 101` I had to include i in the file name. is that not how you get the import procedure to iterate over the files in the folder?

Comment: I think this is a mistake. You do not understand the original macro and you do not understand the code you need to add to it.  Abandon `CtrlSearch` for the moment.

Create a new macro `GenFileNames` and copy into it the code in `CtrlSearch` to create and close the file "Demo.txt". In the middle (after the create and before the close) code a loop that will generate the 101 file names and write them to "Demo.txt".  You need that loop and this will allow you to develop it away from any of the other complexity.

Comment: Stack overflow does not like extended conversations in comments but you do not have enough reputation for chat.  If you look at my profile you will see an email address. Send any further questions to that address.